# Cap production deploy tries to connect with my local machine user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean

This may be something simple that I have missed but when I try to deploy I get

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 178.**.**.235: Authentication failed for user lwa@178.**.**.235
```

The lwa@ user is the user on my mac, I can't seem to be able to change it to the user that is created for the server.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to configure a SSH Key -> http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/

But we need more information like the deploy.rb...

Comment: Thanks for answering, The thing is, I have created ssh keys and can connect fine under the user rails. It's only when I'm using cap that its using lwa@.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put this line in the deploy/production.rb file.

```
server '***.***.***.***', user: 'rails', roles: %w{web app}
```

This fixed the issue.